# Why does my code return 1 when the given number has more zeroes?

Tags: python

If you have another method that can help me I will appreciate your help, I tried my best to write a code that calculates the number of zeroes in a given number.

Here's the code I tried:

```
def zrc(n):

    count=0
    while n%10==0 and n!=0:
        n=n%10
        count=count+1
    return count

    print(zrc(2500))
```

it just gives 1 as output of the code, while it must print 2, but for numbers like 36, it gives 0 as output, what is the problem? I know there must be a problem with that while...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `n%10` is zero, `n` is zero in the next step, so the condition is always fulfilled after the first loop. You probably want to use `//` instead of `%`:

```
def zrc(n):
    count = 0
    while n%10 == 0 and n != 0:
        n //= 10
        count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: oops yes, thanks for your help,I'm always wrong at using such things,i'll fail the course this semester.

Answer (score 0):

```
while n%10==0 and n!=0:
    n=n%10
```

See the above lines. If the condition in the while loop is true, `n=n%10` line will be executed.

This line will make your `n=0` no matter what. For example,

```
2500%10 = 0
25000%10 = 0
250000%10 = 0
```

So, there is no chance that your loop condition will be `True` during the second iteration, so no chance of increment `count` variable more than once.

So, no matter what is your `n` is, you always get the output `1`.

In your code, Change this:

```
n=n%10
```

To this:

```
n=n/10
```

An alternative way, might help you.

```
from collections import Counter
def zrc(n):
    valDict=Counter(str(n))
    return valDict['0']

print(zrc(2500))
```